# JQuery Slow Window Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm using Google Chrome right now and my html page runs perfectly fine without the jquery source within it. I use the Google API url below but when I load my page it takes about 30 seconds or more to load up.

```
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"
```

Comment: this js file is a core of your script.you should have another js file or an script that you can change delay time load.search in your codes ...

Comment: Give us the website url. It's probably other scripts you are running that are slowing it down. Also try minifying your JS. https://javascript-minifier.com/